# how to delete int object in django

Tags: django, object, sql-delete, django-management-command

After filtering and updating I have to delete the objscts, How to solve the isuue,

**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'delete'**

```
 def handle(self, *args, **options):
       trees.objects.filter(old=True).update(new=False).delete()
```

My objective is to first filte all the old trees as True and new as False then updating I have to delete all the object list.

Answer (score 0):

You then filter with `old=True, new=False`, so you do *not* `update`:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    trees.objects.filter(old=True, new=False).delete()
```

Comment: I am getting this eror "You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async."

Comment: @GeorgeMollet: where do you use asynchronous calls...

Comment: In "python manage.py shell_plus"

Comment: But here you are implementing a custom management command...